# Windows 10 installer does not install basics miniconda or Anaconda packages

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, package, installation

so after downloaded Anaconda and/or Miniconda installations, I tried to install both of them, without success. After a quick installation, I opened the installation folder and checked that the basics packages were not installed. [Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JCVl.png). I tried to open the "_conda.exe" file in Windows terminal and trough normal clicking. No results.
Inside the "pkgs" folder [Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbBHO.png), I found folders named with the packages' names, but with only 1 file inside. [Inside the package folder, only the Folder "INFO" was found and, within it, this file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opLq6.png)
Besides that, inside the "pkgs folder", I found the packages in .conda or .tar.bz2 format. [Photo 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATFnf.png)This happened in both installations (Anaconda or Miniconda). I downloaded the latest version of each one.
I had an old Anaconda installation previous, but I removed it before this event using "Revo Uninstaller".
I am using Windows 10 Pro, 64 bits.

Comment: Putting aside the issue of missing files, does the installation actually work correctly? Can you use Conda? What do you mean by _basics packages_ ?

Comment: The installation finishes quick, but ok. No problem detected in the log. I can't use conda, unfortunately. By _Basic Packages_ I mean those showed in photo 4, that is, the packages that are installed with Miniconda or Anaconda. Is there another way to collect information to show for you, through windows terminal?

Comment: _I can't use conda, unfortunately._ What happens when you try? Is Conda in your path? At this point the only advice I can really give is to remove all traces of Anaconda and Conda from your computer, and start over from scratch.

Comment: I can't use any kind of conda or python terminal, because they aren't available for me. When I am inside the Miniconda folder and call a PowerShell terminal and type the command "conda info", it shows:" conda-info is not recognized as an internal or external command". I added Conda folder to my path. No results until now. I removed the pyhton keys from registry, located at HKEY/CurrentUser/Software/Python and at KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python.

Comment: _At this point the only advice I can really give is to remove all traces of Anaconda and Conda from your computer, and start over from scratch._